# Swift display core-data on a label

Tags: swift, core-data, label, schema

I wanted to know how I would get my app that uses core data to save user data to print the stored data (preferable in a string) when I press "display" on a label.

Thanks.

Here's my code for my insert function; what would it look like to put it on a label named 'display'?

```
    @IBAction func insertStudent(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let context = getContext()
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Contacts", in: context)

    let contact = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: context) as! Contacts

    contact.name = name.text
    contact.address1 = address1.text
    contact.address2 = address2.text
    contact.city = city.text
    contact.grade = grade.text
    contact.state = state.text
    contact.zip = zip.text

    var error: NSError?

    //save the object
    do {
        try context.save()
        status.text = ("saved!")
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        status.text = ("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } catch {

    }

  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure whether I have understood you correctly but if you just want to try to fetch data from CoreData and display it on a label you could do something like that: 
Make sure that `CoreData` is imported. Add the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` delegate to your class and create a global variable `var controller: NSFetchedResultsController<Contacts>!`.
Then create a function which tries(!) to fetch the data:

```
func attemptFetch() {
    let context = getContext()
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Contacts> = Contacts.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    controller.delegate = self
    self.controller = controller

    do {
        try controller.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```

`controller.fetchedObjects` holds now an array with all the the data from the `Contacts` entity and with `controller.fetchedObjects?[index].name` you can access the `name`attribute of the the data at index `index`. Now you just have to create some kind of loops which iterates through this array and looks for the data you want to display with `display.text = controller.fetchedObjects?[index].name` to your `display` label (Don't forget to call the `attemptFetch`function first).